# How do I make a neura network classify an image to image using TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

So, I've already tried usng tensorflow to classify images to masks, but when I try to generalize it to images instead of masks I encounter a lot of problems, e.g. problems with tensor sizes, although both images are preproccessed by the same algorithm.

How do I do it?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import cv2
from scipy import io
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

images = []
for i in range(1,5):
    url = 'C:/dataset/photos/%04d.png'%(i);
    img = cv2.imread(url);
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    images.append(tf.convert_to_tensor(img));

masks = []
for i in range(1,5):
    url = 'C:/dataset/masks/%04d.png'%(i);
    mask = cv2.imread(url);
    mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    masks.append(tf.convert_to_tensor(mask));

base = keras.applications.DenseNet121(input_shape=[128,128,3], include_top=False, weights='imagenet');
skip_names = ['conv1/relu', # size 64*64
              'pool2_relu',  # size 32*32
              'pool3_relu',  # size 16*16
              'pool4_relu',  # size 8*8
              'relu'        # size 4*4
              ]
skip_outputs = [base.get_layer(name).output for name in skip_names]

downstack = keras.Model(inputs=base.input, outputs=skip_outputs)
downstack.trainable = False;

from tensorflow_examples.models.pix2pix import pix2pix
upstack = [pix2pix.upsample(512,3),
          pix2pix.upsample(256,3),
          pix2pix.upsample(128,3),
          pix2pix.upsample(64,3)];

inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=[128,128,3])
down = downstack(inputs)
out = down[-1]
skips = reversed(down[:-1])
for up, skip in zip(upstack,skips):
    out = up(out)
     out= keras.layers.Concatenate()([out,skip])

out = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, 3, strides=2, padding='same', )(out);

unet = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
#Ресайзаем картинки и маски
def resize_image(image):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = image/255.0
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (128,128))
    image = tf.reshape(image, [128,128,3]);
    return image;
def resize_mask(mask):
    '''mask = tf.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1)
    mask = tf.image.resize(mask, (128,128))
    mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.uint8)
    return mask'''
    mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.float32)
    mask = mask/255.0
    mask = tf.image.resize(mask, (128,128))
    mask = tf.reshape(mask, [128,128,3])
    return mask;

X = [resize_image(i) for i in images]
y = [resize_mask(m) for m in masks]

train_X, val_X,train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
train_X = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_X)
val_X = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(val_X)
train_y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_y)
val_y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(val_y)
train_X.element_spec, train_y.element_spec, val_X.element_spec, val_y.element_spec;

train = tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_X, train_y))
val = tf.data.Dataset.zip((val_X, val_y))

'''def brightness(img, mask):
    img = tf.image.adjust_brightness(img, 0.1)
    return img, mask

def gamma(img, mask):
    img = tf.image.adjust_gamma(img, 0.1)
    return img, mask

def hue(img, mask):
    img = tf.image.adjust_hue(img, -0.1)
    return img, mask
def crop(img, mask):
    img = tf.image.central_crop(img, 0.7)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, (128,128))
    mask = tf.image.central_crop(mask, 0.7)
    mask = tf.image.resize(mask, (128,128))
    #mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.uint8)
    return img, mask

def flip_hori(img, mask):
    img = tf.image.flip_left_right(img)
    mask = tf.image.flip_left_right(mask)
    return img, mask

def flip_vert(img, mask):
    img = tf.image.flip_up_down(img)
    mask = tf.image.flip_up_down(mask)
    return img, mask

def rotate(img, mask):
    img = tf.image.rot90(img)
    mask = tf.image.rot90(mask)
    return img, mask'''

'''a = train.map(brightness)
b = train.map(gamma)
c = train.map(hue)
d = train.map(crop)
e = train.map(flip_hori)
f = train.map(flip_vert)
g = train.map(rotate)'''
'''train = train.concatenate(a)
train = train.concatenate(b)
train = train.concatenate(c)
train = train.concatenate(d)
train = train.concatenate(e)
train = train.concatenate(f)
train = train.concatenate(g)'''

BATCH = 64
AT = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
BUFFER = 1000
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 800//BATCH
VALIDATION_STEPS = 200//BATCH
train = train.cache().shuffle(BUFFER).batch(BATCH).repeat()
train = train.prefetch(buffer_size=AT)
val = val.batch(BATCH)

example = next(iter(train))
preds = unet(example[0])

pred_mask = tf.argmax(preds, axis=-1)
pred_mask = tf.expand_dims(pred_mask, -1)
plt.imshow(pred_mask[0])
plt.colorbar()

unet.compile(loss= keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy']);

hist = unet.fit(train, validation_data=val, steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH, validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS, epochs=25);

img, mask = next(iter(val))
pred = unet.predict(img)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
for i in pred:
    plt.subplot(121)
    i = tf.argmax(i, axis=-1)
    plt.imshow(i,cmap='jet')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title('Prediction')
    break

plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(mask[0], cmap='jet')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Ground Truth')
plt.show()

#accuracy

history = hist.history;
acc=history['accuracy'];
val_acc = history['val_accuracy'];
plt.plot(acc, '-', label='Training Accuracy');
plt.plot(val_acc, '--', label='Validation Accuracy');
plt.xlabel('Epochs');
plt.ylabel('Accuracy');
plt.legend();
plt.show();

#unet.save("model.h5");
```

And the error message I get is

```
Detected at node 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Fedor\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Проект\Херня.py", line 176, in <module>
      hist = unet.fit(train, validation_data=val, steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH, validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS, epochs=25);
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1564, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 994, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1052, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 152, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 272, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 2084, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      return backend.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5630, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      res = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [49152,3] and labels shape [147456]
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_23362]
```

Comment: Can you add some code that you have tried  so that it is easy to understand for others ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the output layer of the model that you've loaded doesn't match the dimensions of your layers. Either redefine the output layer to match your masks, or you could define your own network to train it. I would recommend the second option so that you have a full understanding of what is going on. This would also make it much easier to match the model to your own data, such that it performs better.

This example might help you:
https://towardsdatascience.com/explaining-face-mask-image-classification-model-using-lime-8f423c601ff9